# Is there a difference between Debug and Release Mode in terms of memory allocation while using c++ in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, c++11, visual-c++

I am running this memory leakage code and I need to know if there is difference in memory allocation

```
int main() {
    while (true) {
        int* i = new int;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in detail on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh712wwf.aspx), in particular: [CRT Debug Heap Details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1.aspx).